# Suppress rendering a UICommand when action method is not accessible to current user?

Tags: jsf-2, authorization, shiro, jsf-2.2

Here's my problem: when rendering a facelet, I don't want to display buttons and links that will execute actions the currently logged in user is not allowed to execute.

What the user *is* allowed to execute is annotated with `@RequiresPermissions` (from shiro-core) and `@ShiroSecured` (from http://balusc.blogspot.de/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html).

So a backing bean might look like this:

```
@Named @ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    @ShiroSecured @RequiresPermissions({ "user:create" })
    public void createUser() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Now, I can replicate this authorization logic in my view like this (I've implemented a subset of shiro's `Subject` interface for the `user` object since the EL-resolver gets confused on the original one...):

```
<h:commandButton id="createUserBtn" action="#{myBean.createUser}" 
    value="create" rendered="#{user.isPermitted('user:create')}" />
```

Obviously, this is duplication I'd like to avoid. I don't think I'm the first to try this, so here goes asking: how do I prevent such a button or link from displaying without explicitly specifying the `rendered` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like: I've not tested the code but I hope it will be ok.

**xhtml**

```
<h:body>     
  <f:event listener="#{myBean.preRender()}" type="preRenderView" />
  <h:commandButton id="createUserBtn" action="#{myBean.createUser}" 
   value="create" /> 
</h:body>
```

**EVENT LISTENER**

```
public class MyBean {
  public void preRender() {
   MyVisitCallback visitCallback = new MyVisitCallback();
       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
       UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
   if (!user.isPermitted("user:create"))
      root.visitTree(VisitContext.createVisitContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()), visitCallback);
  }
}
```

**MyVisitCallback.java**

```
public class MyVisitCallback implements VisitCallback {

@Override
public VisitResult visit(final VisitContext context, final UIComponent target) {
    if (!target.isRendered()) {
        return VisitResult.REJECT;
    }

    if (target instanceof UICommand) {
        target.setRendered(false);
    }

    return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
}

}
```

Comment: Good point about the visitor callback! Though your solution hard-codes  the required permission (what if I have two buttons with differing requirements?) and requires a manual include (that I'm likely to forget - opening a security hole).